# Converting JS code to React.js, can't see what I'm doing wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

quick question I have that I've been stuck on for a while.  I have some vanilla JS code that uploads files and displays what the user has uploaded in the browser.

Below in my code, I'm trying to convert my vanilla JS to react.js code.  In vanilla, I can nest `readAndPreview()` within `previewImages()` but in react.js I get an error `Unresolved method or function readAndPreview()` in my IDE (not console), why so?

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?  I'm open to any sort of criticism :).

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Wall extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.previewImages = this.previewImages.bind(this);
        this.readAndPreview = this.readAndPreview.bind(this);
    }

    previewImages() {
        const preview = React.createElement('div');

        if (this.files) {
            [].forEach().call(this.files, this.readAndPreview());
        }

        readAndPreview() {
            if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
                return alert(file.name + " is not an image");
            }

            let reader = new FileReader();

            reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
                let image = new Image();
                image.height = 100;
                image.title = file.name;
                image.src = this.result;

                let date = Date.now();
                let d = new Date(parseInt(date, 10));
                let ds = d.toString('MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss');
                console.log(ds);

                let initialCountOfLikes = 0;
                const zeroLikes = React.createElement('h1');
                let zeroLikesTextNode = zeroLikes.createTextNode(initialCountOfLikes + " likes");

                zeroLikes.appendChild(zeroLikesTextNode);

                preview.appendChild(image); // makes image appear
                preview.appendChild(zeroLikes); // makes like count appear

                image.ondblclick = function (event) {
                    if (initialCountOfLikes === 0) {
                        console.log("Inside if block");
                        initialCountOfLikes++;
                        console.log("initialCountOfLikes++ => " + initialCountOfLikes);
                    } else if (initialCountOfLikes === 1) {
                        console.log("inside second else if block");
                        initialCountOfLikes--;
                        console.log("initialCountOfLikes-- => " + initialCountOfLikes);
                    }
                    zeroLikesTextNode.nodeValue = initialCountOfLikes + " likes";
                };
            });
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

            document.querySelector('#file-input').addEventListener("change", this.previewImages);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="file-input-wrapper">
                <input type="file"/>
                <label htmlFor="file-input" id={"LblBrowse"}></label>
                {this.readAndPreview()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Wall;
```

Comment: You get an error, but you're not going to share the error message?

Comment: React is vanilla JS and you can't nest function properties short syntax like that in JS.

Comment: @jarmod apologies, I just posted it in my original post.

Comment: @EmileBergeron yes you can, if it's not in a class and declared as, for example, `function x()`, it's possible to nest.  I'd like to know if it's possible in classes.

Comment: You're confusing the [class/object method definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) with the still available [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions).

Comment: When you nest functions like that, you are unable to call it using `this.FUNCTION` - this is because the class is not actually aware of the `readAndPreview` function... You have to do [something like this](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/dxRWLy?editors=1010) ... It would be a lot easier if you could supply a 'working' example using https://codesandbox.io

Answer (score 1):

If you want to nest a local function inside another, you're welcome to do so, but then you need to prefix it with `function`, as in `function readAndPreview() {`. Note that this will only be a local variable inside the containing function of `previewImages` It is not a method on `Wall`. It cannot be accessed from outside `previewImages`, and even inside previewImages you refer to it with `readAndPreview`, not `this.readAndPreview`

Comment: ah ok, is it good practice to use `function` in react.js?  I've always felt it was bad practice to do so, but I guess I could be wrong

Comment: `ah ok, is it good practice to use function in react.js? `Do you have a case that requires it? Local functions aren't common in class components. But if you need one, then by all means use one.

Comment: 1/2 @mrtest -I think you are missing the point. You cannot nest a function within a class method and expect to be able to use that nested function as though it is a member of the class.  The fact you are encapsulating the function within a method means the class is not aware of the nested function, thus you are unable to call it using `this` - only the method which you nest the function in will be aware of `readAndPreview` outside of that, the class is not aware it exists.. This is, of course, on top of the fact you need to use the `function` keyword when nesting like that, again, bc the class

Comment: 2/2... is not aware of its existence.. This has nothing to do with React and functions - this is simply how classes work in general. It's the difference between class methods and functions.